# Maximizing $\frac{\int_r^1xf(x)dx}{2-F(r)}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Consider a continuous distribution on $(0,1)$ with probability distribution function $f$ and cumulative distribution function $F$. Define 
$$g(r)=\frac{\int_r^1xf(x)dx}{2-F(r)}$$
and let $r_M\in(0,1)$ be the value of $r$ maximizing $g(r)$. Is there some positive constant $c$ (independent of the distribution) such that $$\int_{r_M}^1xf(x)dx\geq c\int_0^1xf(x)dx?$$

Note that both the numerator and the denominator are decreasing functions,  and $g(0)=\frac{\int_0^1xf(x)dx}{2}$ and $g(1)=0$. If $r_M$ is too large (so that the desired inequality doesn't hold), then the numerator would be very small, and this can only be compensated if the denominator is also very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $g(r_M) \ge  \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x f(x) dx \overset{\text{def}}{=} \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}X$. Choose $c = 1/2$. Then
\begin{align*}
c \mathbb{E}X = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}X \le \frac{1}{2} (\mathbb{E}X)(2 - F(r_M)) \le g(r_M)(2 - F(r_M)) = \int_{r_M}^{1}x f(x) dx
\end{align*}
Hence we found such a $c$, independent of our distribution.